# Spring - [CSS, JS, Images] Where is my awesome style?

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring, spring-mvc

### I'm new to Spring.

I started a home project, and i decided to use Spring MVC to handle my Servlets  etc. I downloaded a bootstrap theme (to not worry about the style). I had a well worked Servlet, but i wanted to improve my Spring skills, so I started to rebuild the Servlet as a Spring MVC servlet.
When I've done with that, i realized.. all of my css, js contents and obviously my images are not be loaded on the page. 
I searched for opportunities to solve it, as fast as i can.. but i stucked. Some of the css and js loaded but..i haven't seen my awesome bootstrap based theme two days ago. and i'm a bit desperate by now.
Here are some codes, to show u guys how i tried to solve this:
web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/public/"/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property value="/" name="prefix" />
    <property value=".jsp" name="suffix" />
</bean>
```

My project structure:

```
WebContent
META-INF
resources[folder]
    public[folder]
        contactform[folder]
            js files
        css[folder]
            css files
        img[folder]
            images, and folders with more images
        js[folder]
            one js file
        libraries[folder]
            folders with js files (and it contains css files as well(in css-named folders))
WEB-INF
    lib
    spring-mvc-servlet.xml
    web.xml
```

head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">
<title>...</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<meta content="" name="keywords">
<meta content="" name="description">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700|Raleway:300,400,400i,500,500i,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/resources/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link  href="/resources/libraries/nivo-slider/css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/libraries/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/libraries/owlcarousel/owl.transitions.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/libraries/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/libraries/animate/animate.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/libraries/venobox/venobox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link  href="/resources/css/nivo-slider-theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  href="/resources/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My js files called at the bottom of the body :)

Thanks for the aswers, if you need more information, please let me know.. and i'll update my question!

Comment: Can you post the `<head></head>` section so we can see how you've included everything.  Order and position is important and we can't get that from what you've posted.

Comment: *"as u can see on the pictures"*?

Comment: I posted the <head></head>! :) @Archer Cheers! :)

Comment: @kryger sorry mate, i thought i can upload pictures..then i realized i need points for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finally solved!

I've been searching a lot.. until i found the solution. So here are the steps i've done:

1. I've moved all of my css/js/image contents under WebContent/resources/...
2. i've changed the mvc servlet xml
3. and finally.. I've changed all the links and sources

so here is the xml:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property value="/" name="prefix" />
    <property value=".jsp" name="suffix" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and the references

```
<script src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/libraries/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

So, i hope this post will help someone who as desperate as i was.